# how to update image file saved in asset folder?

Tags: css, plotly-dash

I saved images file in asset folder. Now I'd like to update the image. It always shows the old image file even I reboot my pc.

Here are the callback code

```
 html_img_div=html.Div([
            html.Img(id = 'html-img', src = 'assets/img.PNG',
                                style={'height':'200px', 'width':'100%'},
                                draggable='True' ) 
            ],
            id='html-img-div',
            style={'width': '96%','padding-left':'3%', 'padding-right':'3%'}
                            )  

@app.callback(
    [    
        Output("html-img", 'src'),
        Output("html-img-div", 'style'), 
]

def add_image():

  image_well='assets/img.PNG'
  style_image={'height':'300px','width': '100%','padding-left':'6%', 'padding-right':'5%'}  

  return image_well,style_image
```

Comment: Have you specifically cleared your browser’s cache?

Comment: That is awesome, Haworth!  Thank you so much! Yes after clearning browser's cache. it works! Interesting, so even I reboot pc, the cache is still there?